# How to Load Js and CSS in an aspx page at a Certain Position.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I have a Aspx page that will dynamically use anywhere between 10-15 usercontrols at any point of time.  So my requirement is.. Whenever a particular user control is being used, i need a placeholder in aspx page where i can load the css and js for that user control.  The CSS and js mapping will be available on the page load or preinit of the User control.  Any idea how to achieve that?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="usercontrol" TagName="test1" Src="~/path1.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="usercontrol" TagName="test2" Src="~/path2.ascx" %>


<head id="Head1" runat="server">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />

        <meta name="Blah Blah" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        .
.
.
.
.


**<Load Usercontrol1 css>
<Load Usercontrol2 css>**

</head> 

<body>

Whole Aspx Control Body here..
```

```
**<Load Usercontrol1 js here>
 <Load Usercontrol2 js here>**

</Body>
```

Comment: You add your resources to the Style/ScriptManager in your UserControl using a key, so it isn't added more than once even if you add the UserControl more than once.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding the css and js in a tag , you can improve this, using external css and js files, and a framework like require.js  see http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html  and for css

```
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. But Sincce it is dynamic.. i am lookin for suggestions from Code behind..